# Will setting a timeout on a socket work if you are reading a full line using a buffered reader?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing a socket client that sends a line down a socket connection and then waits for up to 45 seconds for a line back from the server.

I'm using a buffered reader like so:

```
Socket socket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;
try {
            socket = new Socket(host, 800);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        socket.getInputStream()));
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            listener.failedToConnectToHost(e);
            return;
} catch (IOException e) {
            listener.failedToConnectToHost(e);
        return;
}

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        out.println("message");
try {
        String response = in.readLine();
        listener.responseRecived(response);
        return;
} catch (IOException e) {
        listener.errorReadingResponse(e);
        return;
}
```

If I add the following line (Or something like it)

```
socket.setSoTimeout(45000);
```

What will happen after 45 seconds assuming that nothing has come through from the other end?

I assume I'll be catching an interrupted exception but I'm sure?

Will this even work? The docs for setSOTImeOut() imply that it's socket.read() that will timeout, I assume that the buffered reader is calling this somewhere down the stack, but assumption is the mother of all screw ups, so I just wanted to check.

Comment: Why won't you test it yourself? I guess TCP conn will close and you'll get EOFException.

Comment: @VictorSorokin why would the connection close?

Comment: 'I assume ...' How exactly could readLine() *not* proceed by reading from the socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BufferedReader.readLine()` method will throw a `SocketTimeoutException` after 45 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I was being lazy and was guilt tripped by my colleague when he saw the question into just testing it myself. Got the same result.

Comment: It's a checked exception, so you'll be forced to catch it or declare it anyway. Since it's a subclass of IOException, it looks like you're already handling it.

Comment: That's probably why I didn't know there was a separate exception. I've got a block that specifically handles the Timeout now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it does work and you get a SocketTimeoutException.